# Excluir Do Banco de Dados sem apagar objetos relacionados

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Tenho um sistema no qual cadastro Instrutores e Alunos, cada Instrutor pode ter vários Alunos sob supervisão e cada Aluno pode ter somente um Instrutor ou não possuir Instrutor.

Meu problema é que na hora de excluir um Instrutor, os alunos relacionados a ele também são apagados, bem como ao excluir o aluno, seu instrutor é apagado. Isso ocorre quando uso a anotação `CascadeType.All`, quando não uso anotação, ele não me permite excluir nada sob hipótese alguma. Qual seria o modo correto de lidar com essa situação?

Quero apagar um Instrutor, sem que seus Alunos sejam apagados, deixando nulo o campo que os relaciona. Assim, também poder apagar um Aluno sem afetar o Instrutor.

Classe Aluno:

```
@Entity
public class Aluno {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_aluno", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_instrutor", nullable = true)
    private Instrutor instrutor;

    @Column(name = "nm_aluno", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "sexo", nullable = false)
    private char sexo;

    @Column(name = "data_nasc", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date DataNascimento;

    @Column(name = "email_aluno", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "login_aluno", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "senha_aluno", nullable = false)
    private String senha;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Instrutor getInstrutor() {
        return instrutor;
    }

    public void setInstrutor(Instrutor instrutor) {
        this.instrutor = instrutor;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return DataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

Classe Instrutor

```
@Entity
public class Instrutor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nm_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "desc_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "email_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "login_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "senha_instrutor", nullable = false)
    private String senha;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "instrutor")
    private List<Aluno> alunos;

    public Instrutor() {
    }

    public Instrutor(String nome, String descricao, String email, String login,
            String senha) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.email = email;
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public List<Aluno> getAlunos() {
        return alunos;
    }

    public void setAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fico me perguntando porque as pessoas postam fotos de códigos e de erros ao invés de copiar e colar os próprios textos.

Comment: Fico me perguntando porque algumas pessoas se importam em fazer críticas nada construtivas, quando não há necessidade alguma disso.

Comment: Não quis lhe ofender, mas é bem claro que TEXTO é bem melhor que FOTOS e facilita as pessoas responderem, e também facilita os motores de busca a encontrar a sua pergunta, a não ser que no futuro tudo funcione com OCR. Ao meu ver é uma critica construtiva, já que vai **ajudar** outras pessoas a **lhe ajudarem**.

Comment: Já que não havia intenção de ofender poderia ser direto explicando tais argumentos, ao invés de de comentar de forma sarcástica. De qualquer forma, irei corrigir a pergunta.

Comment: *NÃO FUI SARCASTICO*  em nenhum momento amigo. Vou lhe fazer uma pergunta simples. Você espera que pras pessoas testarem o teu código elas tenham que redigitar tudo que está na foto? Não é mais fácil postar o código? - Isto vale pra erros de console também. Outra coisa, no futuro usuários com o mesmo problema podem não encontrar a sua pergunta que pode lhes ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o seguinte, deixa como *Cascade.all* mas adiciona o atributo `orphanRemoval = false` na anotação.